# Puppeteer (on Heroku): how to prevent hanging Chromium processes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

We're using Puppeteer in a simple Node.js application to create screenshots "as a service". We're running this on Heroku and quite quickly we see that Chromium processes keep hanging. As a result the server runs out of memory and the application starts failing. Here's the result of a recent `ps` command:

```
  PID                    STARTED       TIME   STAT CMD
    1   Sun Jan 19 20:02:19 2020   00:00:00   S    ps-run
    4   Sun Jan 19 20:02:20 2020   00:00:11   Sl   node app.js
  35   Sun Jan 19 20:02:21 2020   00:00:00   Ss   /usr/sbin/sshd -f /app/.ssh/sshd_co
  36   Sun Jan 19 20:02:21 2020   00:00:00   S    bash --login -c node app.js
  73   Sun Jan 19 20:02:22 2020   00:00:24   Sl   /app/.heroku/node/bin/node /app/app
  78   Sun Jan 19 20:02:22 2020   00:00:24   Sl   /app/.heroku/node/bin/node /app/app
  997   Sun Jan 19 20:33:30 2020   00:00:22   Ssl  /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
  999   Sun Jan 19 20:33:30 2020   00:00:00   S    /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
1012   Sun Jan 19 20:33:30 2020   00:02:02   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
1014   Sun Jan 19 20:33:30 2020   00:00:00   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
1021   Sun Jan 19 20:33:30 2020   00:06:44   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
5030   Mon Jan 20 00:29:34 2020   00:00:15   Ssl  /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
5032   Mon Jan 20 00:29:34 2020   00:00:00   S    /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
5045   Mon Jan 20 00:29:34 2020   00:00:00   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
5051   Mon Jan 20 00:29:34 2020   00:01:26   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
5054   Mon Jan 20 00:29:34 2020   00:04:49   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
7088   Mon Jan 20 03:26:01 2020   00:00:10   Ssl  /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
7090   Mon Jan 20 03:26:01 2020   00:00:00   S    /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
7103   Mon Jan 20 03:26:01 2020   00:00:56   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
7105   Mon Jan 20 03:26:01 2020   00:00:00   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
7111   Mon Jan 20 03:26:01 2020   00:03:06   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
10972   Mon Jan 20 07:02:55 2020   00:00:04   Ssl  /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
10974   Mon Jan 20 07:02:55 2020   00:00:00   S    /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
10988   Mon Jan 20 07:02:55 2020   00:00:22   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
10990   Mon Jan 20 07:02:55 2020   00:00:00   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
10996   Mon Jan 20 07:02:55 2020   00:01:13   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
11660   Mon Jan 20 07:23:37 2020   00:00:03   Ssl  /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
11662   Mon Jan 20 07:23:37 2020   00:00:00   S    /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
11677   Mon Jan 20 07:23:38 2020   00:00:19   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
11679   Mon Jan 20 07:23:38 2020   00:00:00   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
11687   Mon Jan 20 07:23:38 2020   00:01:03   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
12132   Mon Jan 20 07:29:31 2020   00:00:03   Ssl  /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
12134   Mon Jan 20 07:29:31 2020   00:00:00   S    /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
12147   Mon Jan 20 07:29:31 2020   00:00:17   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
12148   Mon Jan 20 07:29:31 2020   00:00:00   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
12156   Mon Jan 20 07:29:31 2020   00:00:59   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
12790   Mon Jan 20 07:56:29 2020   00:00:02   Ssl  /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
12792   Mon Jan 20 07:56:29 2020   00:00:00   S    /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
12805   Mon Jan 20 07:56:29 2020   00:00:13   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
12808   Mon Jan 20 07:56:29 2020   00:00:00   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
12814   Mon Jan 20 07:56:29 2020   00:00:44   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
13268   Mon Jan 20 08:02:03 2020   00:00:02   Ssl  /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
13270   Mon Jan 20 08:02:03 2020   00:00:00   S    /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
13282   Mon Jan 20 08:02:03 2020   00:00:12   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
13285   Mon Jan 20 08:02:03 2020   00:00:00   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
13293   Mon Jan 20 08:02:03 2020   00:00:43   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
13862   Mon Jan 20 08:23:30 2020   00:00:00   Ssl  /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
13864   Mon Jan 20 08:23:30 2020   00:00:00   S    /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
13885   Mon Jan 20 08:23:35 2020   00:00:05   Sl   /app/.heroku/node/bin/node /app/app
13891   Mon Jan 20 08:23:36 2020   00:00:00   Sl   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686
15045   Mon Jan 20 08:39:23 2020   00:00:00   S    ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -o Se
17156   Mon Jan 20 09:09:33 2020   00:00:00   Ss   sshd: u55786 [priv]
17158   Mon Jan 20 09:09:33 2020   00:00:00   R    sshd: u55786@pts/0
17159   Mon Jan 20 09:09:34 2020   00:00:00   Ss   -bash
17769   Mon Jan 20 09:20:49 2020   00:00:00   R+   ps -eo pid,lstart,time,stat,cmd
```

The application code is quite simple:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      defaultViewport: { width: windowSize.width, height: windowSize.height },
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-infobars', '--hide-scrollbars', '--no-default-browser-check', '--bwsi']
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setDefaultTimeout(20000);
    await page.goto(urlToScreenshot);
    await page.waitForFunction(jsReadyTest, { polling: 500 });
    await page.waitFor(500);
    await page.screenshot({ type: "jpeg", quality: 70 }).then(function (buffer) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="' + urlToScreenshot + '.jpg"');
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
      res.send(buffer);
    });

    await browser.close();
  } catch (exception) {
    res.send('Runtime exception!');
  }
})();
```

Note that we added a 20 second timeout to make sure that the application (and thus the browser) ends before Heroku kills the request after 30 seconds.

What can we do to make sure all Chromium process are always terminated correctly?

Comment: Could you try adding the '--no-zygote' argument?

Comment: Thanks, hardkoded. This seems to be working well so far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `--no-zygote` command argument. According to [the commit](https://codereview.chromium.org/2384163002)

> `--no-zygote` can be used to completely disable the use of the zygote process. This is needed for running Headless Chrome in environments where maintaining a forking
>   server such as the zygote is unnecessary and/or impractical.

Comment: In addition I moved the `await browser.close()` to the `finally` section of the `try...catch` as illustrated in the code example in [this repository](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda). The `--no-zygote` together with this seem to do the job perfectly!